NextJS authentication with user session management
I'm developing a project using Next.js and Spring Boot for a client. The client has a service that uses Single Sign-On, and with this same service, we'll be able to validate if the user is valid.
I share the user's data and password with the API, and the API connects to the service to validate the existence of the user.
For security reasons, we need to use a library for the frontend. We usually use NextAuth, but I'm not sure if it's still the best option in this case. We also need to manage user sessions and allow only one session per user.
Does anyone have any recommendations or if it's compatible to use NextAuth in this case?
I've been trying to deploy with next auth but I'm not sure it's possible.
